# How to stop jquery loop function by a click while starting another loop function

Tags: jquery, css, function, loops, animation

Hi I'm quite a beginner at programming, so I am not so that familiar with using jQuery but I want to solve a problem with it.

I am kind of trying to make a "animation/Slideshow", where I have two different images of green smoke that fades in and out so it kind of moves like 'real' smoke. I can do that in jQuery so it's looping, but I want to stop this function of the green smoke looping when I click a specific button while another similar looping function starts, but with images of another color of smoke, like red or blue.

I have this code in jQuery:

```
function startSlideshow(){
    $(".greensmoke1").fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000); //13000
    $(".greensmoke2").delay(5000).fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000, startSlideshow); //55000
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    startSlideshow();
});
```

My css:

```
.greensmoke1 {
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(game/scene11.png);
    width: 880px;
    height: 660px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}

.greensmoke2 {
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(game/scene11b.png);
    width: 880px;
    height: 660px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

I don't know how to make a button that stops the loop, so I tried to make a clickable box in CSS that when you clicked on it, the smokes "visibility" would be set to "hidden". It worked, but it just seems a bit messy to me.

```
$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(e){
        $(".greensmoke1").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $(".greensmoke2").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
}
```

I kind of want that when you click the #button it will stop the loop but at the same time start a new loop until you then click on another button.

I hope you can help its been bugging me for two days now! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I just tried adding Vladimir's code in like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function startSlideshow(){
        $(".greensmoke1").fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000); //13000
        $(".greensmoke2").delay(5000).fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000, startSlideshow); //55000
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        startSlideshow();
    });

    $("#button").on("click",function(){
        $(".greensmoke1").css ("visibility", "hidden");
        $(".greensmoke2").css ("visibility", "hidden");
        $(".bluesmoke1").fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000); //13000
        $(".bluesmoke2").delay(5000).fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000, startSlideshow); //5500
    });

});
```

I added the ("visibility","hidden"); because I want to stop the green smoke(hide them, even though they are display:none; in css). The button worked with that, because the green smoke disappeared, but it didn't get replace by the blue smoke animation.. even if I didn't add the ("visibility","hidden"); code.

I don't really know what's wrong with this code, because it works when I click the button it hides the smoke, but it won't start adding the blue smoke.. :/

I will try out guest271314's code, then I will come back and update! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // added `class*=smoke` selector for `greensmooke` or `bluesmoke`
    var smoke = $("[class*=smoke]");   
    function startSlideshow() {    
        $(".greensmoke1").fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000)
        .siblings(".greensmoke2").delay(5000).fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(1500).fadeOut(2000, function () {
            if (smoke.data("stop")) {
                smoke.stop(true, true)
            } else {
                startSlideshow()
            }
        });
    };
    startSlideshow();
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        // stop slideshow
        smoke.data("stop", true)
        // check `background-image` , `backgroundColor`
        .css("backgroundColor", smoke.eq(0)
        // toggle `background-image` , `backgroundColor`
        .css("backgroundColor") === "rgb(0, 128, 0)" ? "blue" : "green")
        // start slideshow
        .data("stop", false);
        startSlideshow()
    })
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var smoke = $("[class*=smoke]"); 

    function startSlideshow() {

        $(".greensmoke1").fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000)
        .siblings //13000        
        
    (".greensmoke2").delay(5000).fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(1500).fadeOut(2000, function () {
            if (smoke.data("stop")) {
                smoke.stop(true, true)
            } else {
                startSlideshow()
            }
        }); //55000
    };
    startSlideshow();
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        smoke.data("stop", true)
            .css("backgroundColor", smoke.eq(0).css("backgroundColor") === "rgb(0, 128, 0)" ? "blue" : "green")
            .data("stop", false);
        startSlideshow()
    })
});
```

```css
.greensmoke1, .greensmoke2 {
    background-position: center;
    background-color: green;
    width: 880px;
    height: 660px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div class="greensmoke1"></div>
<div class="greensmoke2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Its somewhat like that! But what if I want to add 2 other image from the css to toogle? Because when I write it like this, the button won't response on a click:      
         .css(".bluesmoke1", smoke.eq(0)
         .css(".bluesmoke2"))

Comment: @Alex378 Try `.css("backgroundImage", smoke.eq(0).css("backgroundImage") === "url(game/scene11.png)" ? "url(game/path/to/other-image)" : "url(game/scene11.png)")` , where `/path/to/other-image` would be `url` of image to toggle in . The stacksnippets example utilizes `backgroundColor` , though the pattern is same : 1) stop animation; 2) check current background (color or image); 3) toggle background (color or image); 4) start animation . See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ ,  http://jsfiddle.net to post demonstrations of pieces

Comment: it kind of worked! :) So thank you!  I got the green smoke(first images) to change to one blue smoke(another image), even though I wanted it to loop between two different images of blue smoke. so it changes from two images of green smoke looping to two other images of blue smoke. It only worked for me when I wrote it like this:  .css("backgroundImage", smoke.eq(0).css("backgroundImage") === "url(game/scene11.png)" ? "url(game/bluesmoke.png)" : "url(game/bluesmoke.png)")

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#button").on('click',function(){
             $(".greensmoke1").fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000); //13000
             $(".greensmoke2").delay(5000).fadeIn(2000).delay(1500).fadeOut(2000, startSlideshow); //5500
        }
    }
```

or something similar. I think you can use any element instead of `#button`.
Let me know if it helps.